# I am getting an error of timeout while deploying resources to AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am learning terraform, and am deploying resources to `ap-south-1` . However, I notice that I cannot deploy resources to any region, other than `us-east-1` . To make sure that I am using the right Access Keys, I tried using the Root account Access keys. Still same issue.

After applying terraform apply, I am getting the following error :-

```
    Error: Retrieving AWS account details: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller   identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 25, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post "https://sts.ap-south- 1.amazonaws.com/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
    │
    │   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
    │   on demo.tf line 11, in provider "aws":
    │   11: provider "aws" {
    │
```

I did the following :-

1. Used Admin account Access and Secret key to test
2. Used Root account credentials to test (in case there were some issues with admin credentials)
3. Made sure there is a default region (set to ap-south-1)
4. Made sure there are no spaces in Keys
5. Made sure that the region `ap-south-1` is active in the account

Comment: Is STS enabled for that region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an `endpoints` configuration block in your provider definition? It looks like you have an extra space in the value for `sts`, based on the error message:

```
sts.ap-south- 1.amazonaws.com
```

If not then please share your provider definition and also clarify where you are running the `terraform apply` from - your own machine, or an instance on AWS? If from your own machine, please verify you can connect to sts.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com, as from the error message you are getting a timeout.